# Run Sequelize migration after deployment to App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, sequelize.js, gcloud

I have create a sample project for myself to try Node.js with Sequelize on Google App Engine.

I can run the project locally and it works fine, however when I deploy it to App Engine `gcloud app deploy`

I get the following error:

```
{
    name: "SequelizeDatabaseError",
    message: "ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE: Table 'sql8175762.Likes' doesn't exist",
    parent: {
        code: "ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE",
        errno: 1146,
        sqlState: "42S02",
        index: 0,
        sql: "SELECT `id`, `code`, `likes`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Likes` AS `Likes`;"
    },
    original: {
        code: "ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE",
        errno: 1146,
        sqlState: "42S02",
        index: 0,
        sql: "SELECT `id`, `code`, `likes`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Likes` AS `Likes`;"
    },
    sql: "SELECT `id`, `code`, `likes`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Likes` AS `Likes`;"
}
```

Thats because the Sequelize migration doesnt run however I do have it specified in npm start command:

```
"scripts": {
    "deploy": "gcloud app deploy",
    "start": "npm install & sequelize db:migrate & NODE_ENV=production node ./bin/www"
},
```

I have never used app engine for node deployment and I am not even sure if the steps I am talking are correct to deploy, migrate and run the app.

Does anyone have any tips regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your setup, but do you have sequelize-cli package dependency, also have you tried adding a .sequelizerc file in your root directory and add the paths for your config, migration and models? Example:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    'config': path.resolve('./', 'config/config.js'),
    'migrations-path': path.resolve('./', 'src/server/migrations'),
    'seeders-path': path.resolve('./', 'src/server/seeders'),
    'models-path': path.resolve('./', 'src/server/models')
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same experience, the problem is that for some reasons you have to add `tableName` and `freezeTableName: true` property in the defining model. for instance:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const File = sequelize.define('File', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    courseId: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName: 'files'
  });
  File.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
  };
  return File;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Im a little late to this question, but in case others are looking, it's worth noting that the example script shown uses & between the commands.

This will background each command and immediately run the next, so there's a good chance that both `npm install` and `sequelize db:migrate` are still running when node launches.

If you're on a unix system (Mac/Linux) You can test this locally by creating a file called `./test.sh` containing

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Starting long process ..."
sleep 5
echo "Long process done"
```

and then from the command line running

```
chmod +x test.sh
./test.sh & echo "Running second process"
```

Changing the commands to && should fix this, ie:

```
npm install && sequelize db:migrate && NODE_ENV=production node ./bin/www
```

Answer (score -1):

you should use `&&` instead of `&` in your start command.

`&` means to run the command at background.

`&&` means "logic and" so that the shell will run the command one by one and wait for each returned code.